# Monetizar jogos Unity 5 no Windows Phone 8.X

Tags: c#, unity3d, windows-phone, jogos, pubcenter

Como faço para exibir anúncios no meu jogo feito no `Unity 5` para a plataforma do `Windows Phone 8.X`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para fazer isso basta seguir os passos de monetização de um aplicativo comum do `Windows Phone`, temos dois tipos de anúncios:

- **Banner:** Uma faixa de diversos tamanhos para ser exibida constantemente no app.
- **Interstitial:** Um novo formato, onde quando chamado a tela toda é ocupada por um vídeo de produtos.

Mas como foi citado o `Unity 5`, devemos usar o conceito de `interoperabilidade` para exibir o anúncio em determinado momento do game.

> `Interoperabilidade` é a capacidade de um sistema (informatizado ou não)
>   de se comunicar de forma transparente (ou o mais próximo disso) com
>   outro sistema (semelhante ou não).
>
> *Fonte:* [*Wikipédia*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperabilidade)

Demostrarei como incluir o anúncio `Interstitial` (o mais comum), para isso deve-se acessar seu [Painel de Desenvolvimento](http://dev.windows.com) e adicionar um bloco de anúncio no registro do seu jogo.

No caso como será exportado para o `Windows Phone` devemos fazer tal interoperabilidade criando eventos que possam ser manipulados no `Visual Studio`, então vamos criar um `script C#` no `Assets` do nosso jogo:

**Arquivo:** Interop.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public static class Interop
{
    /*
     * EventHandler é o tipo de evento trabalhado no desenvolvimento para WP.
     *
     * Criamos variáveis de evento para  mostrar e requirir o anúncio (você pode 
     * criar outras para outras ações, como ao fechar anúncio.
     */
    public static event EventHandler ShowInterstitialEvent;
    public static event EventHandler RequestInterstitialEvent;

    public static void ShowInterstitialAd()
    { /* Quando chamamos Interop.ShowInterstitialAd() ele chamará 
         ShowInterstitialEvent do outro sistema (no VS) */
        if (ShowInterstitialEvent != null)
        {
            ShowInterstitialEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public static void RequestInterstitialAd()
    { /* Quando chamamos Interop.RequestInterstitialAd() ele chamará 
         RequestInterstitialEvent do outro sistema (no VS) */
        if (RequestInterstitialEvent != null)
        {
            ShowInterstitialEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

O `RequestInterstitialAd` deve ser chamado uma tela antes da qual você quer exibir seu anúncio, no meu caso chamei-o no script de movimento do personagem:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playermoviment : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        Interop.RequestInterstitialAd();
    }
}
```

O próximo passo será abrir o `script` onde queremos chamar a abertura do nosso anúncio, no meu caso criei um `gameover.cs` onde apenas voltarei para o jogo quando houver um `click(touch)` na tela.

**Arquivo:** gameover.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameover : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Application.LoadLevel("01"); //Volta para a scene do meu jogo
        }
    }
}
```

Devemos chamar nosso método `ShowInterstitialAd` no momento em que quisermos abrir o anúncio, além disso criaremos variáveis públicas e estáticas para controlar nosso anúncio, no caso usarei as variáveis:

- `internet`: vai definir se a internet do aparelho está o não ligada.
- `closeAds`: irá definir se o anúncio foi fechado, para retornamos a captar touch para o jogo.

Vamos para o novo código do `gameover.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameover : MonoBehaviour {

    /* Variáveis de controle
     * closeAds como false, pois o meu anúncio será chamado no Start da tela
     * internet como true (apenas para definir um valor padrão
     */
    public static bool closeAds = false; 
    public static bool internet = true;

    void Start () {

        if (internet) { /* iremos chamar o método de mostrar anúncio  
                           somente se a internet estiver ligada. */
            Interop.ShowInterstitialAd();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        /* Captamos o controle (no caso, o touch reiniciar o jogo)
         * somente se a variável closeAds estiver como true 
         * (por isso declarei como false)
         */
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && closeAds) {
            Application.LoadLevel("01");
        }
    }
}
```

Terminamos os passos que devíamos fazer no `Unity`, agora bastamos exportar nosso game para `Windows Phone 8.X` (sugiro para `Windows Phone 8.1`, para ficar idêntico ao meu), antes de abrir o `Visual Studio`, baixe e instale o `Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK`: [Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=518026)

Com ele instalado, e o projeto aberto no `Visual Studio`:

1 . Abra o arquivo `Package.appxmanifest`, na aba `Capabilities` marque
    a opção `Internet(Client & Server)`.

2 .  Clique em `References` com o botão direito e vá para `Add Reference...`, procure por alguma que contenha no nome "`AdMediator`", marque-a e clique em `OK`.

3 .  Abra o arquivo `MainPage.xaml.cs`, e adicione as seguintes referências:

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

4 .  Dentro da classe `MainPage : Page` declare a variável:

```
private InterstitialAd ad = new InterstitialAd();
```

5 .  Agora dentro do método `MainPage()` após a linha `this.InitializeComponent();` chame os eventos daquela classe `Interop` que criamos no `Unity`:

```
Interop.RequestInterstitialEvent += Interop_RequestInterstitialEvent;
Interop.ShowInterstitialEvent += Interop_ShowInterstitialEvent;
```

Segue os métodos dos eventos já prontos para teste:

```
void Interop_RequestInterstitialEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  // Quando chamamos RequestInterstitialAd, no script de movimentação do player
    // Define aquela variável como true ou false (se há de fato internet no aparelho)
    gameover.internet = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

    if (gameover.internet)
    {  /* se a internet estiver ativa, ele marca closeAds como false, 
          para ser feito o bloqueio dos controles do game enquanto o 
          anúncio estiver na tela. */
        gameover.closeAds = false;
    }
    else
    {  /* se a internet estiver desligada, ele marca closeAds como true, 
          para aceitar controles na tela onde tem o script gameover. */
        gameover.closeAds = true;
    }
}

void Interop_ShowInterstitialEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Quando chamamos ShowInterstitialAd, no gameover.cs
    if (gameover.internet)
    {   // Apenas se a internet estiver ligada ele requiri o anúncio
        ad.RequestAd(AdType.Video, "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "11389925");
        ad.AdReady += ad_AdReady; // cria evento para quando carrega-lo
        ad.ErrorOccurred += ad_ErrorOccurred; // evento de erro ao carrega-lo
    }
}
private void ad_AdReady(object sender, object e)
{  // Quando anúncio tiver sido carregado
    ad.Show(); // mostra anúncio
    ad.Completed += ad_Completed; // quando usuário espera tempo do anúncio
    ad.Cancelled += ad_Cancelled; // quando usuário cancela o anúncio
}

private void ad_ErrorOccurred(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
{  // Quando ocorre erro ao carregar o anúncio
    gameover.closeAds = true; // ele seta a variável como true para permiter touch
}

private void ad_Completed(object sender, object e)
{  // Quando usuário visualiza totalmente o anúncio
    gameover.closeAds = true; // ele seta a variável como true para permiter touch
}

private void ad_Cancelled(object sender, object e)
{  // Quando usuário cancela anúncio (apertando Escape ou no X)
    gameover.closeAds = true; // ele seta a variável como true para permiter touch
}
```

Lembrando que a linha `ad.RequestAd` deve ser alterada, colocando o `id` do seu anúncio gerado pelo [Painel de Desenvolvimento Windows](http://dev.windows.com). Esses que coloquei aí são os que a Microsoft disponibiliza para testes.